# How to make my Telegram Bot to add me back to a private channel?

Tags: telegram, chatbot

I have a Telegram Bot and I HAD a Private channel. I added my bot to this channel as an Administrator so it can send messages on this channel using the API. It's ok, everything's working fine.

But now, I accidentally deleted the channel from my chat list. My bot is still an administrator and is not failing on sending the messages to the channel.

I guess the channel still exists, and the bot is the only administrator on it.

I want to know how can I make my bot add me back to the channel, as I can't do it by myself, because the channel is private. I made the bot backend using C#, I have the ChatID and the Bot Token.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found by myself. Just make a post request to:
https://api.telegram.org/bot[Token]/exportChatInviteLink
Passing the chat_id parameter, and it'll return the invite link.

But there's a catch: When I added the bot to the channel, I did not allowed it to invite others... So now I'm locked out for sure.